# VIM: change default behavior of delete

Tags: vim

The delete command will yank the deleted text, but it's not my expected behavior. I just want to delete the text without overwriting my yanked text. Is it possible to change the default behavior with config? PS: I don't want to use another command to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `d` and `:d[elete]` can be confusing because they behave like "Cut".

To make `d` "really" delete, you must specify the "black hole register" (`:help "_`):

```
"_d
```

You can map `d` to `"_d`:

```
nnoremap d "_d
```

but I'd keep the original command as is, though.

Answer (score 1):

As romaini said, original command for d is good the way it works and I wouldn't advise to change it.

What you can do though is mapping `"_d` with `<leader>d`

In my case leader key is `,` so instead of pressing `"_d` I will write `,d`

```
" shortcut to delete in the black hole register
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
vnoremap <leader>d "_d
" shortcut to paste but keeping the current register
vnoremap <leader>p "_dP
```

Comment: It looks suspiciously [like](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc#L150-L153) my own `vimrc` ;-)

Comment: Indeed you gave the same answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993851/how-to-delete-not-cut

I received the tip from a collegue so you probably could be the patient zero :)

Thanks for that!